# MySQL how to select the first non null value in group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, null, extract

I have this table

```
ID  user    test
-----------------
1   john    aaaaa
2   john    aaaaa
3   john    bbbbb
4   john    NULL
5   john    ddddd
6   sonya   NULL
7   sonya   cccccc
8   sonya   dddddd
9   sonya   aaaaaa
```

And I need to write a query to extract the first non null value of test for each user

if I do a group by

```
SELECT
    user,
    test,
FROM table
GROUP BY user
```

I obtain this resultset

```
user    test
-----------------
john    aaaaa
sonya   NULL
```

but sonya has a null value, I would like to obtain this:

```
user    test
-----------------
john    aaaaa
sonya   cccccc
```

Now, I know that there are ways to obtain sums, count, max, min, etc. from a group by, but I wish to know if there are any ways to get the first non null value

anyone can help?

Comment: `GROUP BY` without any aggregation is pointless. In most SQL implementations your code would be illegal.

Comment: Try `MIN(test)` :)

Comment: Remove NULLs with `WHERE IS NOT NULL` and you will be left with "**TOP N rows**" task that is widely documented on SO and Web in general.

Comment: Without a specification for ordering the rows, the notion of determining which value is "first" doesn't have any meaning. We could easily give preference to a non-NULL value with an aggregate function, e.g. MIN(test) or MAX(test) will both return non-NULL values before a NULL value.  If we need the rows for a given user ordered by `id` column, that's a different ball of wax ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
select id, user, test
from T
where id in (
     select min(id) 
     from T as tin 
     where tin.user = T.user and tin.test is not null 
     group by tin.user
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inner join ond the subquery for min(id) (first row ) group by user

```
  select m.id, m.user, m.test
  from my_table m
  INNER JOIN (
       select user, min(id) as min_id
       from my_table 
       where test is not null 
       group by user
  ) t on t.uset = m.user and t.min_id = m.id
```